# Authorize with multiple roles

Tags: authentication, asp.net-core, authorization, claims-based-identity

The application is developed on asp.net core 3. Faced with the authorization problem, when the user has many roles.

**Roles for users**:

```
public enum UserRole
{
   None = 0x0,
   View = 0x1,
   ConfirmAlarm = 0x2,
   ObjectScaling = 0x4,
   SchemeEditor = 0x8,
   ObjectEditor = 0x10
}
```

**Claims**

```
private async Task Authenticate(User user)
{
   var claims = new List<Claim>
   {
      new Claim(ClaimsIdentity.DefaultNameClaimType, user.Login),
      new Claim(ClaimsIdentity.DefaultRoleClaimType, ((UserRole)user.Role).ToString()),
      new Claim("uGroupId", user.GroupId.ToString()),
      new Claim("uInfo", user.Info),
      new Claim("uTheme", user.Theme)
   };
   ClaimsIdentity id = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, "ApplicationCookie", 
   ClaimsIdentity.DefaultNameClaimType, ClaimsIdentity.DefaultRoleClaimType);
   await HttpContext.SignInAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, new 
   ClaimsPrincipal(id));
}
```

**Controller Method:**

```
[Authorize(Roles = "View")]
[HttpPost("[action]")]
public async Task<string> SomeAction()
{
   //...some code
}
```

If the user has all the roles of the "View, ConfirmAlarm, ObjectScaling, SchemeEditor, ObjectEditor" available, then he cannot be authorized for the method in the controller.

What could be the problem? Need to create a custom AuthorizeAttribute?

**UPDATE**

Added two classes:
**RolesRequirement.cs**

```
public class RolesRequirement : IAuthorizationRequirement
{
    public string RoleName { get; }

    public RolesRequirement(string roleName)
    {
        RoleName = roleName;
    }
}
```

**RoleHandler.cs**

```
public class RoleHandler : AuthorizationHandler<RolesRequirement>
{
    protected override Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context, RolesRequirement requirement)
    {
        string roles = context.User.Claims.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Type == ClaimsIdentity.DefaultRoleClaimType).Value;
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(roles))
        {
            if (roles.Contains(requirement.RoleName))
            {
                context.Succeed(requirement);
            }
        }

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

Add policies to startup.cs

```
services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("View", policy => policy.Requirements.Add(new RolesRequirement("View")));
    options.AddPolicy("ConfirmAlarm", policy => policy.Requirements.Add(new RolesRequirement("ConfirmAlarm")));
    options.AddPolicy("ObjectEditor", policy => policy.Requirements.Add(new RolesRequirement("ObjectEditor")));
});
```

And add the attributes before the controller method.

```
[Authorize(Policy = "View")]
[Authorize(Policy = "ObjectEditor")]
[HttpPost("[action]")]
public async Task<string> SomeAction()
{
   //...some code
}
```

Comment: Don't use roles, its not recommended approach (just there for backwards compatibility). You should prefer claims based authorization  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/claims?view=aspnetcore-3.0

Comment: @Tseng I will study the documentation. Thank.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try below line :

```
ClaimsIdentity id = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
            ClaimsIdentity.DefaultNameClaimType, ClaimsIdentity.DefaultRoleClaimType);
```

Instead of :

```
ClaimsIdentity id = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, "ApplicationCookie", 
            ClaimsIdentity.DefaultNameClaimType, ClaimsIdentity.DefaultRoleClaimType);
```

`CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme` is `Cookies` , which matches cookie's default authenticationScheme in `Startup.cs`:

```
services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
  .AddCookie();
```

**Updated :**

You can manually check the claims :

```
services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("AllowedView", policy =>
    {
        policy.RequireAssertion(context =>
        {

            var roles = context.User.Claims.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Type == ClaimTypes.Role)?.Value;

            var  listRolesElements = roles.Split(',').ToList();


            return listRolesElements.Contains("View");
        });
    });
});
```

And apply policy on the controller which need `View` permission :

```
[Authorize(Policy = "AllowedView")]
```

Comment: In startup.cs there is such a setting. Changed ClaimsIdentity at your advice. Anyway, error 403.

Comment: Check what is value of role in User.Claims after user is authenticated.

Comment: user has all the roles of the "View, ConfirmAlarm, ObjectScaling, SchemeEditor, ObjectEditor"

Comment: Yes it works. But since many roles were expected, now I will create a separate class with the processing of all possible options. Thanks =)